# setuptools not found when installing local package in development mode with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am developing a Python package, and would like to install it in development mode using `pip`. When I run `pip install`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` telling me that `setuptools`  is missing:

```
$ pip install -e my-package/
...
  Running setup.py develop for my-package
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/user/my-package/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/user/my-package/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps --user --prefix=
         cwd: /home/user/my-package/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

This confuses me, as I do indeed have setuptools:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (45.2.0-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  espeak-ng-data gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 libao-common libao4 libaudio2 libdotconf0 libespeak-ng1
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 libpcaudio0 libsonic0 libspeechd2 python3-brlapi python3-click
  python3-colorama python3-louis python3-pyatspi python3-speechd sound-icons
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins xbrlapi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 231 not to upgrade.
```

and I can import it without error in regular python:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, Nov 23 2021, 15:27:38) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>>
```

I can even invoke the exact part of the command that's giving an error without getting any error myself!

```
$ /usr/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize'
$
```

Why doesn't pip find setuptools? It's also worth noting that `pip install my-package` works without the `-e` flag for development mode.

My python/pip executables:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python            [a symlink to /usr/bin/python3.9]
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3           [a symlink to /usr/bin/python3.8]
$ which pip
/home/user/.local/bin/pip
$ which pip3
/home/user/.local/bin/pip3
```

Comment: Linux distro and version?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Hm, trying running it like this... `python -m pip install -e my-package`

Comment: Exact same error comes up. I've already troubleshooted this a bit with some colleagues and verified that all the python/pip versions line up well enough, but we're all completely stumped. It's frustrating to no end that it works without the `-e` but not with it! What does pip do differently with `-e` that allows an error like this to happen?

Comment: Can you run `which python`, `which python3`, `which pip`, `which pip3` and update your question with what it shows. Also are you using venv or anything like that?

Comment: Post edited. And no venv.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241157/discussion-between-teddybearsuicide-and-danica-scott).

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/75514846/5320906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing this:

`sudo python setup.py develop`

from the package directory worked in the end. I can't explain why the other methods didn't work, but this was a workaround for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue previously and the following steps worked for me.

1. Install `setuptools` using pip.
   Pypi page: https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/.

   ```sh
   python -m pip install setuptools
   ```
2. Verify that `setuptools` is installed.

   ```sh
   python -m pip list
   ```

   [image]
3. Attempt to re-install your package again.

   ```sh
   python -m pip install -e my-package/
   ```

Comment: This doesn't help me. I've already got `setuptools` installed (just verified again) and I still get the error. There must be something else going on

Comment: Is setuptools available when you do a `pip3 list`?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working, only if...

Upload your code to GitHub and install from there.
This worked for me.

Install it like this:

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/sarimbinwaseem/rsimageconvertor.git@main
```

```
pip install git+<link to repo.git>@<branch>
```