# pip says version 40.8.0 of setuptools does not satisfy requirement of setuptools>=40.8.0

Tags: python, pip

I am seriously stumped with this one and can't find any questions that match.

If I run `pip3 show setuptools` or `pip2 list`, both say that `setuptools 40.8.0` is installed, but when I try to install a module locally, from a local source code directory, I get the error that says `No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0`

Due to access and firewall restrictions, I have to install the module into my home directory and using what's already installed on the system.

This worked with the previous version of the module, but now it's failing.

Comment: "*…when I try to install a module locally, from a local source code directory…*" What command did you run? Please show the text of the command and the entire text of the error message (traceback). Even if you have `setuptools` 40.8.0 installed a package that explicitly declared `setuptools` as a dependency requires `setuptools` distribution to exist in the local directory.

Comment: To install packages on an offline host you need to download all dependencies recursively (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/7976758), move them to the offline host and install. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Comment: @phd: I'll have to see if something changed  between the first version installed and the current version.  I'm running the same commands that worked with the earlier version. I'll re-type the command, I can't copy/paste to/from the system. --- That said, setuptools 40.8.0 is installed in ```site-packages``` under ```…/python/lib```. Do I actually need to install the packages under ```$HOME```, even if they're under the main Python install?

Comment: I had similar issues when installing a pip package like this: ``pip3 install setuptools torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118`` Setuptools is there in the lib of the venv, but the torch install can't find it. Was not able to work out why.

Comment: @user1603472 I fixed it by running `pip install lit` or whichever library failed right before the setuptools error.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem trying to build psycopg from source, using downloaded dependencies on an air-gapped machine.

I did this initially :

```bash
$ python3.11 -m venv tmp-venv
$ . tmp-venv/bin/activate
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.3.1
setuptools 65.5.0
$ mkdir deps
$ pip download --destination-dir=deps wheel tomli==2.0.1 backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1 typing_extensions==4.7.1 psycopg==3.1.9 psycopg-c==3.1.9
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=deps wheel tomli
```

I then executed

```bash
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=deps psycopg[c]
```

which errored out with

```
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Looking in links: deps
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=49.2.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=49.2.0
      [end of output]
```

The solution, gleaned from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5268), was to add the [--no-build-isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation) flag so that `pip` would find the `setuptools` installation.

```bash
pip install --no-index --find-links=deps --no-build-isolation psycopg[c]
```

[Build isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation) is a feature of PEP518 in which the build process does not look for build-time dependencies (such as setuptools) in the local environment. The `--no-build-isolation` flag disables this feature so that the local setuptools installation is used for the build.

Comment: Of note: when Pip uses build isolation (this has nothing to do with PEP 518, BTW), it will create a new virtual environment for build-time dependencies. Where PEP 518 comes in is that `pyproject.toml` specifies build-time dependencies, which Pip should then decide to ensure *in the virtual environment*. But this requires bootstrapping, which may have failed on OP's machine for any number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel I'll try to review this answer later this week.